# Does the scattering data, in any way, justify the simplistic picture of hadrons?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, scattering, quantum-chromodynamics, protons

The structure of the neutron or the proton is extremely complicated. It is not a simple bound state of three valence quarks. However, the simplified picture allows us to explain various properties of the neutrons and protons such as their charge, spin, magnetic moment, baryon number, etc.

I know that the scattering data reveals that the proton is more complicated. But, does in any way or in any limit, the scattering data also support this simplistic picture?

Comment: But you have already said it!!" simplified picture allows us to explain various properties of the neutrons and protons such as their charge, spin, magnetic moment, baryon number, etc.". All those are measurements that are fitted with the simpllified model!

Comment: @annav But I think it is disturbing if scattering data cannot justify this simplified/approximate picture in some limit. Don't you think so?

Comment: see figure 6 in this paper https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Proton-structure-and-parton-distribution-functions-Chekelian/234f8096b9383d9c5f3115326fd194d1e2fc9139 . They measured the parton distributions,